# Creating a boxplot from two dataframes

Tags: r, boxplot

I have two separate data frames - each representing a feature (activity, and sleep) and the amount of days that each of these features were recorded by each id number.  The amount of days need to reflect on the y-axis and the feature itself needs to reflect on the x-axis.
I managed to draw the boxplots separately, showing the outliers clearly esp for the one set, however if I want to place the two boxplots next to each other, the outliers do not show up clearly.  Also, how do I get the names of the two features (activity and sleep) on my x-axis?

The dataframe for  the "sleep "feature:

head(idday)

## A tibble: 6 x 2

```
      id  days
   <dbl> <int>
```

```
1 1503960366    25
2 1644430081     4
3 1844505072     3
4 1927972279     5
5 2026352035    28
6 2320127002     1
```

The dataframe for  the "activity "feature:

head(iddaya)

## A tibble: 6 x 2

```
      id  days
   <dbl> <int>
```

```
1 1503960366    31
2 1624580081    31
3 1644430081    30
4 1844505072    31
5 1927972279    31
6 2022484408    31
```

My attempt for sleep:

```
ggplot(idday, aes(y = days), boxwex = 0.05) + 
stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
               width = 0.2) +   
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.9, outlier.color="red")
```

and for activity:

```
ggplot(iddaya, aes(y = days), boxwex = 0.05) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", 
               width = 0.2) +    
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.9, outlier.color="red")
```

I then combined them:

```
boxplot(summary(idday$days), summary(iddaya$days))
```

In this final image the outliers do not show clearly, and I want to name my x-axis and y-axis.

Comment: Instead of copy-pasting your data set, can you copy paste the output of `dput(your_df)` so that we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve your task. One way could be:

If your dataframes are coalled df_sleep and df_activity then we could combine them in a named list and add a new column `feature`, then plot:

```
df_sleep
df_activity

library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(list(sleep = df_sleep,  activity =  df_activity), .id = 'feature') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = feature, y=days, fill=feature))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare these two boxplots with each other I recommend to use the same range for your y-axis. To achieve this you first have to combine both data frames. You can do this with `inner_join()` from the `dplyr` package.

```
data_combined <- inner_join(idday, iddaya, 
                            by = "id", 
                            suffix = c("_sleep", "_activity"))
```

Then you need to transform your data frame into *long-format* with `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr` package:

```
data_combined_long <- data_combined %>% 
                        pivot_longer(days_sleep:days_activity, 
                                     names_to = "features", 
                                     names_prefix = "days_", 
                                     values_to = "days")
```

After that you can again use `ggplot()` to create your boxplot. But now you have to define that you want your x-axis to represent your features:

```
ggplot(data_combined_long, aes(y = days, x = features), boxwex = 0.05)+
   stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
               width = 0.5) + 
   geom_boxplot(alpha=0.9, outlier.color="red")
```

Your plot should then look like this: [image]

Comment: The first method worked very well, thanks.  I am cautious to use the second method as some records don't have matching values in both dataframes and I don't  want to loose them.

Comment: I am happy I could help. However, depending the question you are trying to answer with this data, I strongly recommend using only complete observations. As it otherwise could lead to wrong conclusions.

Comment: Yes, I did indeed use complete data frames, which include 33 observations. (I was not entirely sure how to post it here.)